# How can i inherit JS class in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to inherit `mail.chat_client_action` class in my custom module, but I am getting `undefined` as output.

Here is my code:

```
odoo.define('my_module.inherit_calss_name',function (require){

   var chatClient = require('mail.chat_client_action');

   //Imported some other modules

   console.log('chatClient',chatClient);//Prints undefined

   chatClient.include({
     //my code here.
   });
});
```

In the console, I am getting an error `chatClient is undefined`.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the Odoo javascript code and it appears that `mail.chat_client_action` does not actually return anything useable.

For example: in `mail.chatter` (`addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js`) the code looks like:

```
odoo.define('ls_base.Chatter', function (require) {
"use strict";

<CODE CODE CODE>

var Chatter = form_common.AbstractField.extend({

<chatter chatter chatter>

});

core.form_widget_registry.add('mail_thread', Chatter);

return Chatter;

});
```

But in `addons/mail/static/src/js/client_action.js`:

```
odoo.define('mail.chat_client_action', function (require) {
"use strict";

<CODE CODE CODE>

core.action_registry.add('mail.chat.instant_messaging', ChatAction);

});
```

There is no `return` in the core code, so `require('mail.chat_client_action')` is `undefined`